# Pass a variable number of arguments from batch file to python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, arguments, parameter-passing

Let's say I run the python script like this:

```
python foo.py --value 4 -v --generate
```

The script is using argparse and contains a wide array of different args.

I'm looking to condense the `python foo.py` part to a batch file called foo so I can run:

```
foo --value 4 -v --generate
```

I know that I can get the arguments to a batch file by using `%1, %2, %3...` but how can I pass all of the arguments to the python script in the same order?

Comment: Use `%*`. Type `call /?` for help. See cheat sheet https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html.

Comment: ... unless you have quoted and really complicated parameters. check [this](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2836&sid=2eed757ca29b5dcc99497165395e9b19&start=45) out.